# HTML file size changes after reading and writing to a new file using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YMLeZDSKpURGAcWITWbhDBDYLOTiLRP7/view?usp=sharing) of File size - **1128 KB**.

Following shows the size of the above HTML file:
[image]

Following is my code to just read and write the HTML file to a new file `sample.htm`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#path to HTML file
html = r'C:/Users/USER/Downloads/form10-ka.htm'
with open(html, 'r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    soup  = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'html.parser')
    
with open("sample.htm", "w", encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(str(soup))
```

The above code generates a `sample.htm` as below:
[image]

File size - **1082 KB**.
The same HTML when written to a new file changes the file size. It seems the `&nbsp;` and a few other characters are not preserved.

I tried another code to preserve the `&nbsp;` as below:

```
with open("sample-1.htm", "w", encoding='utf-8') as file:
     file.write(str(soup.encode(formatter="html").decode()))
```

The above code generates a new file `sample-1.htm` as below:
[image]

Filesize - **1106 KB**.
This preserves the `&nbsp;` and yet again is **lesser than the original file size**

What else can be done to maintain the original file size(An increase in file size should also work) !!

Any leads would be helpful

Comment: "Access denied". Make the file public.

Comment: U should be able to access now @GordonAitchJay

Comment: You're out of luck, unfortunately. BeautifulSoup doesn't preserve the original indentation, or the order of tag attributes. Why do you need the output file size to be the same as the input?

Comment: It needn't necessarily be the same as input file size. But currently, it is reducing. Is there any way to not reduce the size (increasing is fine )

Comment: This results in a larger output file, which still looks very similar: `file.write(soup.prettify(formatter=None))`. What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve here, though? It's an unusual requirement for the output to be larger.